# My Shinydashboard App is not deploying : Bundle does not contain manifest file

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm new to RShiny and I decided to create my first App.

When I lauch my app with this command it executes right away and everything is fine.

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when I'm trying to deploy my app to the Shinyapps.io servers I have this error

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 547685425 failed: Error parsing
>   manifest: Bundle does not contain manifest file: data/données.xlsx

It looks like Shiny can't find my document *données.xlsx* which is where I'm reading data for my apps but the first thing I do in my code is setting my directory.

Here is my Code :

```
setwd("C:/Users/Baillargeon/Desktop/R_PROG/RShiny_test")

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(rsconnect)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

donnees <- read.xlsx("data/données.xlsx", sheetName = "donnees", encoding = "UTF-8")

[...]

ui <- dashboardPage(


      dashboardHeader(title = "Employés"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Jeu de données",tabName="Donnees",icon=icon("database")),
          menuItem("Graphiques",tabName="graph",icon=icon('signal'))
        )
      ),

      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(

          tabItem(tabName="Donnees",
                  h2("Données"),
                  DT::dataTableOutput("donnees")
                 ),

          tabItem(tabName = "graph", h2("Graphiques"),
                  fluidRow(
                    box(plotlyOutput("plot_sites")),
                    box(plotlyOutput("plot_sexe"))

                          )
                 )
                )
        )
)


server <- function(input,output){

  output$donnees = DT::renderDataTable({

    donnees
  })

  output$plot_sites <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(final_sites, labels= final_sites$Site, values= final_sites$Freq, type="pie",
            textposition = 'inside',
            textinfo = 'label+percent',
            showlegend = FALSE
           ) %>%
          layout(title="Répartition des employés selon l'arondissement")
  })

  output$plot_sexe <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(final_sexe, labels= final_sexe$Sexe, values= final_sexe$Freq, type="pie",
            textposition = 'inside',
            textinfo = 'label+percent',
            showlegend = FALSE
    ) %>%
      layout(title="Répartition des employés selon leurs Sexe")
  })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)


rsconnect::deployApp("C:/Users/Baillargeon/Desktop/R_PROG/RShiny_test")
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

remove `setwd("C:/Users/Baillargeon/Desktop/R_PROG/RShiny_test")` as first line. 
When you are deploying on shinyapps.io , it is a linux environment. so `C:/` makes no sense.

Moreover, by default your working directory is where your `ui.R` and `server.R` are located. So, your data folder path should be relevant to that. Which looks like so from your code.

read documentation [9.4 “Disconnected from server” messages](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Troubleshooting.html#build-errors-on-deployment)

Hope it helps